# Can I change values in a PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have an alarm manager who fires a pending intent every few minutes. Can I change this pending intent somehow in the `OnReceive` method of the by the intent specified class.
And furthermore, is it possible to change that intent from a class that has no direct conection to the intent?

I looked it up, but haven't found anything helpful so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to Update the PendingIntent with the new extras  values

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);    
 i.putExtra("position", tag);   
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, tag, i,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: thank you, my mistake was to use the intent provided by the method call. Stupid mistake. But how can I change this pending intent outside the `onReceive` call? There I have no `context` object to create my intent.